# Different html code based on screen resolution

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Currently I manage the CSS code differently based on screen size using  and it works fine:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 40em) {
    my code
    }
```

Now, what I'm trying to achieve is to have a piece of html code placed differently based on the screen resolution.

For instance my div id="news_box" would be placed in my header wrapper on desktop. Whereas on mobile phones, div id="news_box" would be placed in the footer wrapper.

How could I achieve that?

Many thanks,

Comment: You can create those elements and hide them. When the resolution is mobile show them and hide unwanted ones. Just an idea. You can also use js to achieve your thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to manipulate the `DOM` using `CSS` in that way, but you could use a JavaScript hack:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var width = this.innerWidth;
    if(width < 400) {
        document.getElementById('footer-id').appendChild(document.getElementById('news_box'));
    }
});
```

Or maybe assign a class to it and have the element appear in both the header and footer (although, you would want to change the ID):

```
#footer-id .news_box {
    display: none;
}
#header-id .news_box {
    display: block;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 40em) {
    #footer-id .news_box {
        display: block;
    }
    #header-id .news_box {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With this you go through the diffrent resolutions. You have to change the values for your "news_box" for every different one.
e.g. For desktops you have a float:left box which will be not present in the css part for your mobiles.
example:

```
    /* Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width: 760px) {
    #news_box { max-width: 760px }
…
}

/* midle screens */
@media only screen and (min-width: 980px) {
    #news_box { max-width: 980px; float:left; margin: 0 auto; }
}

/* big screens */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    #news_box { max-width: 1280px; float:left; margin: 0 auto; }
…
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I'm trying to achieve. I'm fine changing the CSS code based on screen resolution. What I'd like to do is the other way round: change the HTML code.

Comment: Okay sorry then, I misunderstood.